# npm ERR! addLocal Could not install error on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm trying to do `npm install` on my project root where I have the `package.json` file. There is a git module in the dependencies of my `package.json` which I would like to install.

I have npm version `3.8.5` installed.

When I run `npm install`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\<username>\npm-global\Temp\npm-16864-a5deb5d4\git-cache-e02b7085\
ed488e2db50edd81e6db23865772ae34d4e446c5
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\<some-folder-path>\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\<some-folder-path>\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.5
npm ERR! path C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\<module-name>\0.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall scandir

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ute-
gulp-tasks\0.0.2\package.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\<module-name>\0.0.2\package.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I can see the files created for the error npm ERR!
`C:\Users\<username>\npm-global\Temp\npm-16864-a5deb5d4\git-cache-e02b7085\
ed488e2db50edd81e6db23865772ae34d4e446c5`

and

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\<module-name>\0.0.2\package.tgz`

but for some reason npm could not access it.

Unfortunately, I could not find a solution for this issue anywhere.

It would be great if someone can help me out !!!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Anyone have faced a similar issue in Windows?
Please help! I'm stuck with this for sometime.

Comment: Can you try update your `nodejs` to v5.x (latest)? I think `npm 3` just work fine with `node v5`

Comment: And there are not so much breaking change between node `v4` and `v5`, so it's ok to update